# How can I escape this error message after logging in?

Tags: 20.04, xrandr

My computer boots up correctly but once I've entered my password to log in, I receive this error message:

```
Error found when loading /home/mus/.xprofile:

xrandr: cannot find output "VGA-0"

As a result, the session will not be configured correctly. You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
```

Then there is an `OK` button which I cannot activate/reach in any way.

I created `.xprofile` because my screen resolution wasn't available so followed steps to add it manually, and then to automate on booting.

As a result, I receive this error message and cannot proceed beyond this point.

The mouse and keyboard aren't registered on-screen, even though both are functioning correctly.

How can I escape this and log in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out - this may come in useful for anybody experiencing the same problem.

I connected a wireless mouse then switched the mouse on, after which point the input was detected after which point the cursor subsequently appeared.

I expect that (re)connecting a mouse and/or keyboard would also have the same effect.